# How to set maven version to the @version tag in Javadoc?

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

I want to use the javadoc plugin to generate the Java Documentation. 
The @version should be the Projekt Version but I can't get it to work.

This is my pom file:

```
...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <defaultAuthor>Meeresgott</defaultAuthor>
                    <defaultVersion>${project.version}</defaultVersion>
                    <version>true</version>
                    <author>true</author>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>javadoc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
...
```

But the version tags don't shows up at any point. 
Is there some tag that i should place in the commentate section in the java class?

Something like:

```
/**
*
* @version <useMavenVersion>
**/

public class MyClass {


}
```

Comment: Based on the docs of the [maven-javadoc-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/jar-mojo.html)  I don't see `defaultAuthor` nor `defaultVersion` as possible configuration parameters for the goal `jar`. But the goal [`fix`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/fix-mojo.html) contains those things which means you need to call `mvn javadoc:fix`  instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! With this configuration it works!

First you have to run this command: "mvn javadoc:fix"
After that you can build your javadoc as normal with "mvn install" or "mvn javadoc:jar"

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <defaultAuthor>Meeresgott</defaultAuthor>
                    <defaultVersion>${project.version}</defaultVersion>
                    <version>true</version>
                    <author>true</author>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>update</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>fix</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>javadoc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```